# Deserializing Gson NullPointer?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse JSON to get some values.

```
{
"username":"shobhit@gmail.com",
"roles:
      {
       "ROLE_Student_Trial":true,
       "ROLE_student":true,
       "ROLE_Student_Unlimited":true
      },
"type":"student",
"lastLogin":1441305986000,
"token":"123"
}
```

This is how I am deSerializing it

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();

String userName = obj.get("username").getAsString();
JsonObject roles = obj.get("roles").getAsJsonObject();

Boolean isTrial = roles.get("ROLE_Student_Trial").getAsBoolean();
Boolean isStudent = roles.get("ROLE_Student").getAsBoolean();
Boolean isUnlimited = roles.get("ROLE_Student_Unlimited").getAsBoolean(); // LoginTest.java:31

long lastLogin = obj.get("lastLogin").getAsLong();
int token = obj.get("token").getAsInt();
String type = obj.get("type").getAsString();

System.out.println(userName);

if(isTrial){
    System.out.println("Student trial is on last login " + timeConverter(lastLogin));
}
if(isStudent){
    System.out.println("Student access level");
}
if(isUnlimited){
    System.out.println("Student is unlimited as " + type + " and its token = " + token);
}
```

I was trying to get values of inner JSON, 
but I am getting NullPointerException.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at loginActivityHttpURL.LoginTest.main(LoginTest.java:31)
```

Comment: Which line is LoginTest.java:31?

Comment: @Pythonian, you *are* aware that JSON is case sensitive, right? I see a "student" in place of "Student" there

Comment: @TobiaTesan Ohh thanks, no I didn't knew, I am new for JSON and GSON. Thats the issue !

Comment: BTW consider perhaps using GSON with an appropriate structure and avoiding deserializing by hand altogether. It's tedious and, as you are finding out, error prone.

Comment: @TobiaTesan Yes, sure I will try that method too. As I am new to JSON, I am doing trial and error thing with all possible ways. But I will consider your suggestion in practicality. I would also love to know more about JSON and gson. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering to my own question.

JSON is case sensitive, so at `("ROLE_Student")` gson wouldn't find any value. Instead I corrected it with `("ROLE_student")` and it worked.

Thanks to @Tobia Tesan

Comment: if you solved your own problem, go ahead and accept your own answer!

Comment: It takes 2 days to accept own answer. waiting for same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Boolean isStudent = roles.get("ROLE_Student").getAsBoolean();
```

to

```
Boolean isStudent = roles.get("ROLE_student").getAsBoolean();
```